# group_by and summarize flattening to single observation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have duplicate observations in a data frame on certain fields; I'd like to flatten the frame by a unique factor, and take the existing value from those duplicate fields.  Some fields are `NUM`, others `INT`.
Here's the code I've written:

```
MyData %>%
  group_by(courseUser) %>%
  summarize(USER=last(courseUser), finalPercent = max(FINAL_PERCENT)) -> MyData
```

`courseUser` is the factor I'd like to group by
Each `courseUser` has the same value for `FINAL_PERCENT`, so by requesting max, I hope to de-dupe the entry for that observation.

But it appears that I'm only passing a SINGLE value for the `finalPercent`.
Source data is diverse and correctly cast as an int.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data that illustrates your issue? Paste the output of `dput(my_data_sample)` into your question.

Comment: Figured out the answer: had plyr loaded, which confused the group_by command.  Detached plyr and it's all good.